# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . if else statement

Tags: javascript, global-variables

it not works and said Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .:

```
var UNITS = {
    if (localStorage.getItem('lang')=='zh'){//if language chinese then it is translated Newton
   fullText:{  
        N: "牛顿",
   }, 
   }
   else (
   text:{  
        N: "N",
    } 
    )
```

it works before like this

```
var UNITS = {
   fullText:{  //how each unit will be printed in the dropdown box
        N: "Newton",
   }, 
text:{  //how each unit will be printed in text
        N: "N",
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this is simply incorrect JavaScript code. I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through some basic JavaScript tutorials and/or book. You've taken property initializers from the inside of an object initializer and tried to use them as freestanding syntax. You can't do that.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make some sort of "expression if".  Like most languages with C derived syntax, Javascript's `if ... else` blocks don't do that, they're only at the statement level.

Comment: so what i should do?  i want if language is zh then var units initiialize as Chinese, if it is english then it turns out Newton

Answer (score 1):

Could use a ternary to determine which value to use

```
var fullText = localStorage.getItem('lang') == 'zh' ? '牛顿' : 'N';

var UNITS = {
  fullText: { 
    N: fullText,
  },
  text: {
    N: "N",
  }
}
```